# Can not create connection to SQL server using RJDBC

Tags: r, jdbc

I just installed the RJDBC library but I am not able to make a connection to the database.  The same connection string works when I use RODBC, so I am not sure why RJDBC is not able to make the connection.  I would be very grateful if you could guide me to a solution.  I am using R in MAC OSX 10.8.2

```
drv <- JDBC("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver","/Library/Java/Extensions/sqljdbc4.jar", "‘")
conn <- dbConnect(drv, "jdbc:sqlserver://data.rsquaredltd.com/****","****","****")
```

The drv objet is created successfully but the conn fails with an error message

```
"Error in .jcall(drv@jdrv, "Ljava/sql/Connection;", "connect", as.character(url)[1],  : 
 com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host data.rsquaredltd.com/SandP, port 1433 has failed. Error: "null. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall."."
```

There are no firewalls blocking and as I mentioned, there is no problem connecting via RODBC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your URL is incorrect. You are using `jdbc:sqlserver://data.rsquaredltd.com/SandP`, that should be `jdbc:sqlserver://data.rsquaredltd.com\SandP`.

The format of the JDBC URL is:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://[serverName[\instanceName][:portNumber]][;property=value[;property=value]]
```

See [Building the Connection URL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) on MSDN for more information.