# Using JDBC Driver for Hive on Amazon EMR in R

Tags: r, jdbc, hive, amazon-emr

Amazon [provides a JDBC Driver](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/HiveJDBCDriver.html) for connecting to Hive.  There is a [JDBC package for R](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RJDBC/index.html) that seems like it should be able to make use of those drivers and allow access to Hive.  In fact, others have clearly been able to access [Hive from R with JDBC](http://henning.kropponline.de/2014/07/13/hive-r/).

I have not been so lucky.  I have successfully used the Amazon drivers via SQL Workbench/J following the [instructions provided by Amazon](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/HiveJDBCDriver.html) to pull some data from Hive.  Therefore, I know that in practice the .jars included in the Amazon JDBC driver are sufficient for connecting to the version of Hive (0.13.1) on my EMR cluster, and I also know that that the SSH tunnel has been set up correctly.

It seems like the following R code should suffice for connecting to Hive on the EMR cluster (following similar configuration options as for SQL Workbench/J and cribbing some notes from the "Using Hive from R with JDBC" blog post"):

```
if (!require("DBI")) {install.packages("DBI");library("DBI")}
if (!require("rJava")) {install.packages("rJava");library("rJava")}
if (!require("RJDBC")) {install.packages("RJDBC",dep=TRUE);library("RJDBC")}
JDBCLib <- "~/AmazonHiveJDBC/1.0.0.1000/"
for(l in list.files(JDBCLib)){ .jaddClassPath(paste(JDBCLib,l,sep=""))}
drv <- JDBC("com.amazon.hive.jdbc3.HS2Driver", paste0(JDBCLib,"HiveJDBC3.jar"))
conn <- dbConnect(drv, "jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default", user="hadoop")
```

The `JDBC` function returns the drv object without complaint that has a structure that looks like the following:

```
Formal class 'JDBCDriver' [package "RJDBC"] with 2 slots
  ..@ identifier.quote: chr NA
  ..@ jdrv            :Formal class 'jobjRef' [package "rJava"] with 2 slots
  .. .. ..@ jobj  :<externalptr> 
  .. .. ..@ jclass: chr "com/amazon/hive/jdbc3/HS2Driver"
```

However, try as I might, `dbConnect` returns with

```
Error in .jcall(drv@jdrv, "Ljava/sql/Connection;", "connect", as.character(url)[1],  : 
  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.amazon.hive.hive.core.Hive2JDBCDriver
```

I vain I have tried specifying the user in the URL, specifying the dbname, not specifying the user at all, etc.  I have also tried a couple variants of the URL as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14751214/can-not-create-connection-to-sql-server-using-rjdbc), e.g. "jdbc:hive2://localhost\default:10000;user=hadoop", but didn't have any success.  At this point it seems like I am tantalizingly close to success, but not quite getting there.  What error have I made?  How can I correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28211999/r-using-rjdbc-write-table-to-hive), which has received no answer, included `.jinit()` in the example code that they had used to successfully connect to hive.  This was the missing special sauce.  `.jinit()` launches the JVM and must be called prior to adding the jars to the class path.